# jQuery datetimepicker too much recursion error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 3 application and having some issues.  I've got a PartialView which has a submit button.  Code looks something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "IceCream", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "editicecreamform" + @Model.IceCreamID }))
{
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstDateTime, new { @class = "mydatetime" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstDateTime)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SecondDateTime, new { @class = "mydatetime" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstDateTime)
   <input type="submit" value="Save" data-icecream="@Model" />
}
```

and the script portion looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.mydatetime').datetimepicker({
      showSecond: true,
      timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss TT', 
      hourGrid: 4,
      minuteGrid: 10
   });

   $(document).ready(function () {
      var options = {
         target: "#icecreamdetails@(Model.IceCreamID)",
         url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "IceCream")',
         success: UpdateGrid // not germane to discussion
      };

      $("#editicecreamform@(Model.IceCreamID)").submit(function () {
         $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
         return false;
      });
   });
</script>
```

My Edit action looks something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Edit(IceCreamCreateEditViewModel viewModel)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
   }
   return PartialView();
}
```

The error occurs when I edit an entry and make the Name field blank and try to save it.  There's a `[Required]` annotation on the property in the viewmodel and so I get the validation error message.  However, if I then attempt to click on one of my two datetime edits, I get a **"too much recursion"** or **stackoverflow** error.  This occurs in FF as well as IE8.  The error is in the `jquery-ui-datetimepicker-addon.js` file that I'm using, which I got from [http://trentrichardson.com/2010/04/19/timepicker-addon-for-jquery-ui-datepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/2010/04/19/timepicker-addon-for-jquery-ui-datepicker/), at least that's where the debugging tool leads me.

If I just use the jquery datepicker (no time component), I don't get this error at all.

I assume there could be an error in the datetimepicker but as I'm new to jquery and ASP.NET MVC, there's a good chance it's just me not doing something correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: `timeFormat: 'hh:mm;ss TT'` fast question, `;` it's supposed to be there ?

Comment: @ric_bfa mistyped it - should be a colon, fixed that. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it appears that the problem is that my partial view has this line:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-ui-datetimepicker-addon.js")" type="text/javascript"></script
```

and if I move that into the `_Layout.cshtml` instead, it doesn't get referenced twice and the "too much recursion" / stackoverflow issue.